# Error kernel and supervision in Akka: will messages from stale children be delivered to restarted actor?

Tags: scala, akka, actor, error-kernel, akka-supervision

I am trying to follow best practices and apply error kernel pattern in Akka. According to this quote from [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/actor-systems.html):

> If one actor carries very important data (i.e. its state shall not be lost if avoidable), this actor should source out any possibly dangerous sub-tasks to children it supervises and handle failures of these children as appropriate. Depending on the nature of the requests, it may be best to create a new child for each request, which simplifies state management for collecting the replies. This is known as the “Error Kernel Pattern” from Erlang.

... it is a good idea to create children and delegate error prone work to them, concentrating important state in parent/supervisor actor.

In this scenario if actor with important state gets restarted for some reason, do I need to handle messages from it's stale children (that was created before restart)?

Lets illustrate this with example.

Lets asuume I have actors 3 actors: `A` (is parent/supervisor of `B`), `B` (is parent/supervisor of `C`, contains important state) and `C`.

`A`'s supervision strategy is configured to restart it's children on exception.

`C` gets created in `B`'s constructor.

Lets then assume that message `bc` is sent form `B` to `C`. `C` starts to process it (lets imagine that it runs long running computation there) and, once done will reply to `B` with `cb`.

Now, lets assume that **before** `cb` is sent to and processed by `B` `A` sends message `ab` to `B`. This message causes `B` to throw an exception and as a result of `A`'s supervision strategy decision `B` will be restarted.

As a child of `B` `C` will be stopped during `B`'s restart (new `C'` will be created in `B`'s constructor).

Will restarted `B` receive `cb` from `C` that was sent before `B` got restarted?

If yes, will `sender` of `cb` (`C`) be considered a child of restarted `B`? And will actor ref's of `C` and `C'` be equal (assuming `C` and `C'`s names are equal)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your restarted `B` will receive its response from the first `C`.  If `C` is performing long running work and its parent fails, the restart of `B` actually won't happen until `C` has finished its long running work.  As part of restarting `B`, the original `C` is stopped (not restarted) and a new `C` is created (what you are calling `C'`) that is a child of the restarted `B`.  The first `C` will not be a child of the restarted `B` however.

When the first `C` finishes, its `sender` ref is still valid and this response can still be delivered to that refs mailbox even though it is about to be restarted.  When `B` is restarted, it is able to preserve what was in its mailbox before the restart, thus it receives and processes the `cb` message immediately after starting back up.

I drafted a little code example to show this behavior:

```
import akka.actor._
import concurrent.duration._

object RestartExample extends App{
  case object Start
  case object AB
  case object BC
  case object CB

  val system = ActorSystem("test")
  val a = system.actorOf(Props[A])
  a ! Start

  class A extends Actor{
    val b = context.actorOf(Props[B], "myb")
    import context.dispatcher

    def receive = {
      case Start =>
        b ! Start
        context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(3 seconds, b, AB)
    }
  }

  class B extends Actor{
    println("new B actor instance created")
    val c = context.actorOf(Props[C], "myc")
    def receive = {
      case Start =>
        c ! BC
      case CB =>
        println("got a CB from C")
      case AB =>
        throw new RuntimeException("foo")
    }
  } 

  class C extends Actor{
    println("new C actor instance created")
    def receive = {
      case BC =>
        Thread.sleep(10000) // simulating long running behavior
        println("done with long processing...")
        sender ! CB
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply and code snippet. However, there are few corrections to be made before I can accept your answer. First of all, `C` never gets restarted. `C` gets `context.stop`'ed and another actor will be created in place of it (this is quite important difference since no restart hooks will be called on `C` and there will be new `C'` with different actor ref created by `B` after `B` restart). The second thing is answers to my question question about `C` and `C'` refs equality and whether `C` is a child of restarted `B`. The answer is no to both.

Comment: I.e, when processing `cb` `sender == c` and `context.children.toSet.contains(sender)` are `false`. Ammend this info to your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @EugenyLoy, I added your corrections to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains a contradiction:

"Now, lets assume that before cb is sent to and processed by B"
"will restarted B receive cb from C that was sent before B got restarted"

So which one is it? Was `cb` sent before the restart or not?

If C restarts before sending the message, then it is lost. If it was sent before the restart, but not processed by B then it will be in B's mailbox and the new instance of B will receive it.

Basically, I would advice you to design a flow that does not fall apart as soon as one message is lost. When working with Akka, you should *always* assume that any message can be lost at any time.

Edit: forgot the second question: if cb was sent before the restart, and B actually receives it the sender will be an `ActorRef` pointing to the new instance of C. `ActorRef`s and `Actor`s are 2 different entities.